# Cocos2d-html5 and socket.io this undefined

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, socket.io

I am just getting socket.io and cocos2d-html5 to work. Every time a new client connects I want to put a new LabelTTF on the screen.
With application start I create a main layer with a Tilemaplayer as child which is stored in _tilemaplayer.

On my main Layer I have the following code in onEnter:

```
var tilemap = new TilemapLayer();
this._tilemaplayer = tilemap;
this.addChild(tilemap);

socket = io.connect('hostname:port');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('setName', {name: 'Testname'})
})

socket.on('newClient', function(data){
    var testLabel = cc.LabelTTF.create(data.name, "Arial", 32);
    this._tilemaplayer.addChild(testLabel);
})
```

Why does this give me an error that this._tilemaplayer is not defined? I can access it in other functions of my main layer, why not here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think "this" in your socket.on event handler function doesn't equal "this" of your layer or scene.

you need save the pointer of your layer or scene's "this", code follow:

```
var tilemap = new TilemapLayer();
this._tilemaplayer = tilemap;
this.addChild(tilemap);

socket = io.connect('hostname:port');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    socket.emit('setName', {name: 'Testname'})
});

_this = this;
socket.on('newClient', function(data){
    var testLabel = cc.LabelTTF.create(data.name, "Arial", 32);
    _this._tilemaplayer.addChild(testLabel);
})
```